# Liferay add categories to artical hook

Tags: liferay, hook, article

i tried too automaticaly add some categories to an newly created artical via hook. but i don't know which action i should hook into. I tried hook in to the AssetEntry Model actions, But it's a failure. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can override[using hook] JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl's addArticle method and add your logic to add categories to created Journal Article OR else you can have categories default selected by overriding jsp

Comment: You can also create ModelListener using hook for JournalArticle and on method onAfterCreate you can add logic to save categories for article

Comment: @PankajKathiriya ModelListeners should not be used for business logic (and I consider adding categories business logic). I agree with your first comment though - why not post it as an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Categories are populated through asset_categories_selector taglib UI for assets. html/taglib/ui/asset_categories_selector/page.jsp is where categories gets populated.

Comment: This is not the best place to do it. That jsp is for the taglib which it's used for all portal assets.

Comment: @Baxtheman I understand its not the best practice to modify the tld jsps. But in business requirement where you are using certain structure & template and you need to open web content form using this structure & template and have certain categories pre-populated by default. It such case we will be require to Modify it.

Comment: I enforce my opinion, this is not the right way to do it. Instead via hook you can customize `../portlet/journal/article/categorization.jsp`. This is the place you have the control of web content categorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can override[using hook] JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl's addArticle method and add your logic to add categories to created JournalArticle **OR** you can have categories default selected by overriding jsp[categorization.jsp] .